reverse engineering of electronics of games - off topic?
Why is asking about the concepts of a game hardware design is considers to be off topic?
I'm trying to find out the concept of hardware design of a game, which is reverse engineering of the game, I think.
I asked about the most proper SE site to post my question on, and reverseengineering SE sited seemed appropriate.
But when I asked my question on the site, it received negative votes, which means that it's not on topic question,but why is that?
Why are such questions considered to be off topic, and how can I, if possible, make them on topic questions?

The hardware RE is most definitely on-topic, as you can check by looking at the hardware tag.
Negative votes do not necessarily mean "offtopic". The close votes so far were for "too broad"; not sure I agree with the reason but it's understandable since you don't provide much information. The questions work best when you have something concrete to answer, otherwise you get some vague handwaving answers which do not much help the asker or other visitors.
